# how can we pass arguments to a powershell scripts in a file rather than on commandline?

Tags: powershell, arguments, .env

I want to create a .env file or .settings file with all the parmaeters to a powershell script defined there and then just pass that file to .ps1 script. How can we do this?

Tried to pass with -File param but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`-File` denotes the `.ps1` script file to execute and you can only pass arguments to it *directly*.

There is no built-in support for what you're trying to do, but you can:

- create a settings file with `<parameter>=<value>` lines
- parse it into a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) with [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata)
- and pass the hashtable as parameter values via [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting):

Assume a file `test.settings` with the following content (parameter name-value pairs):

```
foo=foo-val
bar=bar-val
```

Assume a target script `test.ps1` that declares parameters `-foo` and `-bar`

You can then use [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, or [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, with its `-Command` (`-c`) parameter as follows:

```
powershell -c "$parms=Get-Content -Raw test.settings | ConvertFrom-StringData; & .\test.ps1 @parms"
```

In effect, the above is the equivalent of:

```
powershell -File .\test.ps1 -foo foo-val -bar bar-val
```